# Problem connecting to linksys wireless using zenwalk

Tags: linux, wifi

I just recently installed zenwalk linux on my machine, and I am having trouble connecting to my wireless router. I am using the appropriate options such as use encryption, WEP passphrase, the correct passphrase, and so on. It sits there for a minute and gives me an error message of "connection failed: bad password". I have tried everything possible in my power as far as troubleshooting goes. I tried running the wireless configuration through terminal, but I don't believe I am skilled enough to do such a task, as I have not been successful thus far.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably start from the basics: identify your wireless card and work out if you have the correct driver:
`lspci | grep -i net` or, if it is a USB device `lsusb`.

There are a few places where you can check if your card is supported:

- [Linux Wireless Support](http://linux-wless.passys.nl/)
- [Wireless Kernel page](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Devices)
- [Hardware Compatibility List](http://www.linuxquestions.org/hcl/index.php?cat=10)

If your card doesn't show up here, you'll likely need to resort to [ndiswrapper](http://ndiswrapper.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/List).

You will then need to make sure you have both the Zenwalk [wireless tools package](http://packages.zenwalk.org/?p=wireless-tools-29-i486-6.txz&zversion=snapshot) and your card's driver and any firmware installed.

After loading your driver, run `iwconfig` to see that you have an interface such as `wlan0` present. Bring the interface up with `# ifconfig wlan0 up`

Scan for an access point with `# iwlist wlan0 scan` and then if you are using a hex key with WEP:

`# iwconfig wlan0 essid "MyEssid" key 1234567890`

Finally provide an IP address to the interface with `# dhcpcd wlan0`

There is a much more detailed step-through of all of this on the [Arch Linux wireless page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless), including troubleshooting and different options for static IPs etc.

It is worth working through the steps methodically as it will give you both a good understanding of what exactly is happening behind the scenes when you move to a network connection manager (like [wicd](http://www.wicd.net/)) and will also pinpoint where exactly your issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried hooking your PC up to the router with an ethernet cable? At least this way you can diagnose if the problem is with the wireless drivers/hardware or if it is at a higher level.